# jQuery - PHP class selector issue

Tags: php, jquery, selector

So I have something like this:

```
<?php foreach($post_array as $post): ?>
    <div class="postBodyWrapper">
        <div class="vid-link">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function() {
                    $(".vidthumb").append("<img class='thumb' src='<?php echo $post->vid_link; ?>'/>");
                });
            </script>
            <div class="vidthumb"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Let's say I have five posts in the `$post_array`. Then the `<div class="vidthumb"></div>` of each post will contain all five images (that are generated from the JavaScript code), instead of only the one that is supposed to. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php $i = 0; foreach($post_array as $post): ?>
<div class="postBodyWrapper">
    <div class="vid-link">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                    $("#vidthumb_<?php echo $i ?>").append("<img class='thumb' src='<?php echo $post->vid_link; ?>'/>");
            });
        </script>                           
        <div id="vidthumb_<?php echo $i++ ?>"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

By giving each `vidthumb` div you want the thumb to appear in a unique ID, you can now target the specific div's instead of the first match.

Comment: aaand that did the job. damn i should have came up with it myself >.<
thanks a lot dude :)

Comment: @Systemfreak Your code was appending that piece of HTML to every div with class of `vidthumb` at that moment in the HTML building. This code just creates unique ids. There's no need to do this, you should just generate your HTML from PHP since you're already doing it for half of it